# If we have 4 different books of history and 6 different books of English.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given $4$ history books and $6$ English books how many ways are there to select $3$ books where at least one of each subject has been selected?

I think it is 7c3.

Comment: It may help to realise that there are only two options: 2 History + 1 English, 2 English + 1 History. Can you figure out how many ways there are for each of these cases?

Comment: They are 2 ways for these options

Comment: So dividing by 120 is 60 ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2 possible cases are case A, $2H + 1E$, and case B, $2E + 1H$.

In case A: you choose 2 of the 6 history books $\binom{6}{2}$ and 1 English book $\binom{4}{1}$ so there are $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1} = 60$

In Case B: you choose 1 of the 6 history books $\binom{6}{1}$ and 2 English books $\binom{4}{2}$ so there are $\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2}=36$

Altogether, there are $60+36=96$ possible ways to select 3 books andhave at least one of each subject.